# involution of affine space fixes a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\tau$ be a polynomial involution of affine space $k^n$ for $k$ algebraically closed, so

$\tau(x_1,...,x_n)=(f_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,f_n(x_1,...,x_n))$

where $f_i$ are polynomials, and $\tau^2=id$. I want to prove, that the set of fixed points of $\tau$ is non-empty. It probably follows from the Lefschetz fixed-point theorem, but I'm sure there must be some trivial argument that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof I know is nontrivial and is explained e.g. by Serre [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0517): it reduces to the case of a finite field of odd characteristic, where the result is clear because in that case affine space has an odd number of points.

Comment: thanks, that's nice, but definitely non-trivial. Considering the fact, that this is an exercise for a first course of algebraic geometry, I'm sure there must be some simple argument

Comment: @scott: well, affine space over $\mathbb{C}$ is noncompact as a topological space, so there's no hope of applying the topological Lefschetz fixed point theorem. The algebraic Lefschetz fixed point theorem concerns *etale* cohomology, which is even less trivial than the reduction to a finite field. So I don't know what argument your professor has in mind.

Comment: whoops, that's my bad! I first read the proof theorem 2.1 which states that we need that "the corresponding fixed points Y and Y' are finite and $etale$ over  Spec($\Lambda$)" and that's what scared me away, but the previous proof (of the actual fact that i need) is actually quite nice - thanks!